# Azure Data Studio - Why Is Restore Option Missing Entirely?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I am doing a simply .bak restore using Azure Data Studio.

Following the instructions available here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=data-studio#tabpanel_1_data-studio

[image]

However, on my Mac, I dont get that option at all.

[image]

I dont understand. is the backup option facility not available in Azure Studio anymore?

Note:

Azure Data Studio details.

```
Version: 1.27.0
Commit: 765c7064d46253d88393e0e1ff78874b6fe8fa64
Date: 2021-03-16T21:18:54.187Z
VS Code: 1.51.0
Electron: 9.4.3
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.2.0
```

Comment: Azure SQL database doesn't support backup from .bak files. Please use .bacpac files instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure SQL database doesn't support backup from .bak files. Please use .bacpac files instead.

You could ref this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/14904228-backup-and-restore-azure-database-to-and-from-bak):
[image]

**Update:**

As for now, you decided to use management studio on windows to solve the issue.

We can't any document talked about the Data Studio UI difference between Mac and Windows. Turn to use SSMS on windows may be another solution.

HTH.

Comment: the .bak part I understand. but in my case, the option to restore itself is missing. that means, even if I had .bacpac files, without the restore button, I am still helpless.

Comment: Hi @Jay, can you try other Azure Data Studio version? Please try this tutorial version： https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15#get-azure-data-studio-for-macos.

Comment: @Jay Please click the pricticeofquery1.database.windows.net to check the restore option.

Comment: Hi @Jay did you get any progresses?

Comment: Leon, The version you have linked (1.27) is the one that I already have. So, that is already done. I am definitely selecting the server before trying to restore. I am starting to think, perhaps on Mac, that option is not there. As of now, I decided to use management studio on windows to solve the issue.

Comment: @Jay well, we can't any document talked about the Data Studio UI on Mac. Turn to use SSMS on windows may be another solution. May I add these to my answer?

Comment: Yes, please do :) in our situation, that is the only thing that works.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue on my Mac. When i connect to the local database server (without selecting a database) i get the option to export / import by right clicking the database name. This however don't work when connecting to an Azure Database server

A workaround is to install the "SQL Server Dacpac" extension from Microsoft from the marketplace inside Azure Data Studio. Then you can export and import from bacpac files using the Data-tire Application Wizard

[image]